# Wordpress Multisite Htaccess Overwrite

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to make a basic folder rewrite that over rides Wordpresses default htaccess.

I need a folder located at domain.com/community/sso/index.php to force resolve as domain.com/community/sso

This is what I recently tried:

````
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^community  - [L]


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /public/404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sso/index.php [L]
</IfModule>```
````

Comment: Where is WP installed? Also clarify purpose of all 3 rules you have shown in question.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, changed sequence of your present rules here(bases on your show rules), couldn't test it. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^community  - [NC,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /sso/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /public/404.php [L]
```